# Calculation in Access Query to Change Based on Dates

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to run a query that will calculate "TOTAL COST". The current code I have is:

```
SELECT [Main Query].SaltInfo_ID, Sum([Main Query].Tons) AS [Total Of Tons], Sum([Main Query].BlastTons) AS [Total Of BlastTons], Sum([Main Query].LiqGal) AS [Total Of LiqGal], Sum([Main Query].LiqBlastGal) AS [Total Of LiqBlastGal], ((Nz([Total Of Tons])+Nz([Total of BlastTons]))*66.63)+((Nz([Total Of LiqGal])+Nz([Total of LiqBlastGal]))*0.182) AS [TOTAL COST]
FROM [Main Query]
WHERE ((([Main Query].EventDate) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY [Main Query].SaltInfo_ID;
```

This works just fine; however I need to change the calculated [TOTAL COST] to calculate values based on the [EventDate]. If the event date was before 7/31/2016, the Tons and BlastTons cost is $66.63 and the LiqGal and LiqBlastGal is $0.182. After 7/31/2016, the cost changed to $50.40 and $0.1594 respectively. Can you please help with the proper coding so that this will calculate properly? I have tried this, and it didn't work:

```
SELECT [Main Query].SaltInfo_ID, Sum([Main Query].Tons) AS [Total Of Tons], Sum([Main Query].BlastTons) AS [Total Of BlastTons], Sum([Main Query].LiqGal) AS [Total Of LiqGal], Sum([Main Query].LiqBlastGal) AS [Total Of LiqBlastGal], IIf([Main Query].[EventDate]<#7/31/2016#,((Nz([Total Of Tons],0)+Nz([Total of BlastTons],0))*66.63)+((Nz([Total Of LiqGal],0)+Nz([Total of LiqBlastGal],0))*0.182),((Nz([Total Of Tons],0)+Nz([Total of BlastTons],0))*50.4)+((Nz([Total Of LiqGal],0)+Nz([Total of LiqBlastGal],0))*0.1594)) AS [TOTAL COST]
FROM [Main Query]
WHERE ((([Main Query].EventDate) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY [Main Query].SaltInfo_ID;
```

When I try to run the query, I get the error: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'IIf([Main Query].[EventDate]<#7/31/2016#,((Nz([Total Of Tons],0)+Nz([Total of BlastTons],0))*66.63)+((Nz([Total Of LiqGal],0)+Nz([Total of LiqBlastGal],0))*0.182),((Nz([Total Of Tons],0)+Nz([Total of BlastTons],0))*50.4)+((Nz([Total Of LiqGal],0)+Nz([Total of Li' as part of an aggregate function."

What I am doing wrong??? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should mention that I am using Access 2010

Comment: Can you try this query: "SELECT SaltInfo_ID, Sum(Tons) AS [Total Of Tons], Sum(BlastTons) AS [Total Of BlastTons], Sum(LiqGal) AS [Total Of LiqGal], Sum(LiqBlastGal) AS [Total Of LiqBlastGal], Sum(IIf(EventDate<#7/31/2016#, ((Nz(Tons,0)+Nz(BlastTons,0))*66.63)+((Nz(LiqGal,0)+Nz(LiqBlastGal,0))*0.182), ((Nz(Tons,0)+Nz(BlastTons,0))*50.4)+((Nz(LiqGal,0)+Nz(LiqBlastGal,0))*0.1594))) AS [TOTAL COST] From [Main Query] WHERE EventDate Is Not Null GROUP BY SaltInfo_ID;"

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: You also need to group by on that expression.

Comment: Velid - I tried your query and it worked perfectly. Exactly what I needed it to do - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A query is not the place to put this sort of logic. You need another table to hold your pricing:

```
create table ProductCosts (Product varchar(255), StartDate datetime, EndDate DateTime, Cost Currency)

insert into ProductCosts(Product, Cost, StartDate,EndDate)
Select 'BlastTons', 66.63, '1/1/1990','7/31/2016'
union select 'LiqGal', 0.182, '1/1/1990','7/31/2016'
union select 'LiqBlastGal', 0.182,'1/1/1990','7/31/2016'
union Select 'BlastTons', 50.40, '8/1/2016','1/1/2050'
union select 'LiqGal', 0.1594, '8/1/2016','1/1/2050'
union select 'LiqBlastGal', 0.1594, '8/1/2016','1/1/2050'
```

Then your final query can be like this:

```
SELECT [Main Query].SaltInfo_ID, Sum([Main Query].Tons) AS [Total Of Tons]
    , Sum([Main Query].BlastTons) AS [Total Of BlastTons]
    , Sum([Main Query].LiqGal) AS [Total Of LiqGal]
    , Sum([Main Query].LiqBlastGal) AS [Total Of LiqBlastGal]
    , ((Nz([Total Of Tons])+Nz([Total of BlastTons]))*BlastTons.Cost)+((Nz([Total Of LiqGal])*LiqGal.Cost + Nz([Total of LiqBlastGal]))*LiqBlastGal.Cost) AS [TOTAL COST]
FROM [Main Query] mq
inner join ProductCosts BlastTons on BlastTons.StartDate <= mq.[EventDate] and BlastTons.EndDate > mq.[EventDate] and BlastTons.Product = 'BlastTons'
inner join ProductCosts LiqGal on BlastTons.StartDate <= mq.[EventDate] and BlastTons.EndDate > mq.[EventDate] and BlastTons.Product = 'LiqGal'
inner join ProductCosts LiqBlastGal on BlastTons.StartDate <= mq.[EventDate] and BlastTons.EndDate > mq.[EventDate] and BlastTons.Product = 'LiqBlastGal'
WHERE ((([Main Query].EventDate) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY [Main Query].SaltInfo_ID;
```

Ideally there is not a join for each type of product but that would involve you changing your `Main Query` first.

Comment: In Access/VBA, date values must be wrapped in _octothorpes_: `Select 'BlastTons', 66.63, #1/1/1990#, #7/31/2016#`.

Comment: @Gustav that's true that `#` will also work but `'` works just fine for me too. My issue is actually with the `Union` statement. Access doesn't like that.

Comment: No, using quotes will not work "just fine" as you get fixed text, not date values. I'm not sure what your unions do, so I can't tell what your issue is.

Comment: @Gustav What issues do you get when using `'`? Because as far as I can see if I try to insert `'7/31/2016'` and `7/31/2016` ends up in my table it seems like there is not an issue. The problem with the `Union` is I get the error `Query input must contain at least one table or query` But if the query is just illustrative then it's fine; I'm not populating all their valid values in this answer anyway.

Comment: The issue you get with quotes is that you don't get date values, just text that looks like. There will be _no_ advantages whatsoever, not even saved key strokes.

Comment: @Gustav I think you're missing that the column being populated is `DateTime` so I **do** get a date. I can't insert text into a `DateTime` column.  The advantage is I don't have to do something different for SQL Server and Access.

Comment: Yes, it may work because Access/VBA will try to cast the string to a date value and - in this case - succeeds. But again, there is zero advantage other than gaining a bad habit that will cause trouble in other scenarios. If you write code for both Access SQL and SQL Server you will, sooner or later, have to handle two varieties.

Comment: I was able to create the table; however, when I tried the final query above, I go the "Syntax error (Missing Operator) in query expression. I did try with both the ' and the # around the date.

Comment: @user7380439 yes...sorry for all the confusion. You should just take that query as an example or subset of your complete data set anyway. do you see the gist of what you need to do in that table though?

Comment: Yes, I get it now that I played around with it a bit. Thank you very much for all of your help!